# Return result from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have problem on Android 4.0.x. When up navigate in **onActivityResult** resultCode is always 0 and Intent is null.

**Navigate up code:**

```
    protected void navigateUp(){
       Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
       upIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

       if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
           TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
           .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
           .startActivities();
       } else {
           NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
       }
    }
```

**Set result code:**

```
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
       Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
       resultIntent.putExtra(SELECTED_POSITION, position);
       setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
       navigateUp();
    }
```

What the problem? It's works on 4.4.x and not works on 4.0.x. Why? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the method `onActivityResult` so your code must be like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
.
.
.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //Do whatever you want 
  }
}
```

Comment: I have these methods :) but resultCode is always 0 and Intent is null.